# Running Selenium/PhantomJS inside a Vagrant box

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, vagrant

I'm trying to set up testing for a Web app using [behaving](https://github.com/ggozad/behaving), which runs on top of [behave](https://github.com/behave/behave) and [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/) - the latter of which in turn uses Selenium to drive PhantomJS. All of this is inside a VirtualBox-provided Vagrant box running CentOS 6.4. I've installed Selenium via `pip`, and I've installed PhantomJS from the [Nux Dextop](http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/) repo.

Trying to run my tests freezes Behave for 30 seconds, then raises:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to GhostDriver'
```

I think I've nailed it down to not being able to open a socket, and indeed, when I try to do this from the Python interactive shell, I can't open any socket to localhost at all. How do I get my tests to run?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had the same problem with the `Can not connect to GhostDriver` error. When trying `phantomjs --help`, I got the error

```
[WARNING] Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (libicui18n.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
```

After installing libicu48 (Ubuntu package), `phantomjs --help` gave me

```
[WARNING] phantomjs: cannot connect to X server
```

This made sense, since I didn't have an X server installed. Then, I [discovered](http://phantomjs.org/faq.html) that phantomjs <= 1.4 requires an X server, but >= 1.5 is pure headless. So, instead of relying on my distro's phantomjs package, I installed it using `npm`, and now everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for  this answer. You saved me a couple hours of head scratching. Where's the tip jar when you nee one?

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the package of libicu48 and gnome-session-fallback for the bug.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libicu48 gnome-session-fallback
```